# Python file i/o position of cursor in r+

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

In python3 is the following statement incomplete:

```
r+
Opens a file for both reading and writing. The file pointer placed at the 
beginning of the file.
```

Doesn't writing to the file in this mode occur at the end of the file, while reading takes place from the beginning of the file?

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of modifying an existing one with a new topic.  It invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is correct.  Writing to the end by default would be `'a+'` (open for reading and appending), but it could still be OS-dependent if you `.seek()` elsewhere.  See [open() documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> ... 'a' for appending (which on *some* Unix systems, means that all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position).

Experimentation on my Windows system confirmed that `'r+'` and `'w+'` start at the beginning of the file, and `'a+'` starts at the end.  With `'a+'` all writes seek to the end before writing, so any following read needs to seek to a previous point in the file or will get nothing.

Comment: @DCR rolled back new question. But try disabling caching. Caching can read ahead. Best practice is to always seek between reads and writes. It’s not a bug.